# React component not re-rendering with new props unless I change key

Tags: reactjs, redux, render, rerender

I'm making an app that displays a lot of graphs, so in order to prevent unnecessary re-rendering I've been going through my components and seeing where I can implement `shouldComponentUpdate` to improve efficiency. But after doing so in some of the higher up components I'm getting a weird bug with the graph component itself. I have the generic `<Graph/>` parent component with this render:

```
render() {
    return(
        <div>
            { this.getGraph() }
        </div>
    );
}
```

and the `getGraph()` essentially returns this:

```
return React.createElement(graphComponentMapping[graphType], {data:this.state.data,...this.state.configuration});
```

where `graphComponentMapping[graphType]` is a `<Table/>` component (or various other ones, but we'll focus on table for now). Now in that `<Table/>` component I render this:

```
return(
    <ReactTable {...this.getParameters()} data={data} columns={columns} />
);
```

and the `getParameters()` function essentially just looks through the configuration prop and gets all the properties relevant to the React Table component.

Now, when I initially render the `<Table/>`, it has the correct configuration (i.e. if I change the initial config the table matches that). But when I update the configuration prop in the `<Graph/>` parent, the table doesn't update accordingly. The render function in `<Table/>` is called again, and if I print `this.props` in the table's render I can see that various configuration properties have changed, e.g. `this.props.defaultPageSize` has changed from say `5` to `3`, but the table doesn't re-render to reflect this. Even in the browser's React dev tools I can see the props have changed.

If I force a complete a re-render of the element by using a random key, e.g.

```
return(
    <ReactTable {...this.getParameters()} data={data} columns={columns} key={Math.random()} />
);
```

then it works, and the table updates when I pass new configuration props. Why doesn't it update when receiving new props, only when I force it to completely re-render?

Comment: removing the dynamic key generation.. what does your `shouldComponentUpdate` look like? also, if you removed that method, does your table update accordingly?

Comment: Probably because one of the `shouldComponentUpdate`s along the way returns `false`? (You can log their return values to check)

Comment: you gave as an example the `defaultPageSize` which may be relevant only in the constructor, and not for the current page size. so, can you give another property that's not rendering when changed?

Comment: @NiritLevi that was it! a bunch of the react-table props only get set in the constructor and don't change. So the component won't update unless I completely re-mount it so it's instantiated with the new prop in the constructor. If you want to post that as the answer I'll accept.

Comment: @Jayce444 its not really an answer to the header so I'm just glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced such problem but that was primarily the way my redux store was setup.
Redux object is reference based so even just updating the properties, it wasn't telling my React component that something has changed. To solve this, I had to create a new object and update value there and then use it, which solved the issue.

this could be the reason they key having a random number is causing your whole component to re-render.